# VB.NET - If string contains "value1" or "value2"

Tags: vb.net, string, if-statement, contains

I'm wondering how I can check if a string contains either "value1" or "value2"?
I tried this:

```
If strMyString.Contains("Something") Then

End if
```

This works, but this doesn't:

```
If strMyString.Contains("Something") or ("Something2") Then

End if
```

This gives me the error that conversion from string to Long can't be done.
If I put the `or ("Something2")` inside the parenthesis of the first one, it gives me the error that the string cannot be converted to Boolean.

So how can I check if the string contains either "string1" or "string2" without having to write too much code?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You have to do it like this:

```
If strMyString.Contains("Something") OrElse strMyString.Contains("Something2") Then
    '[Put Code Here]
End if
```

Comment: I'll go ahead and set this as the answer, since you're a newer user :)

Comment: I'd suggest using the short circuited version of Or, OrElse.

Comment: For clean code please delete the asterisc at the end of strMyString.Contains("Something2")* <<---

Answer (score 14):

You need this

```
If strMyString.Contains("Something") or strMyString.Contains("Something2") Then
    'Code
End if
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't try this.. And such a quick response! :)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answers already given it will be quicker if you use `OrElse` instead of `Or` because the second test is short circuited. This is especially true if you know that one string is more likely than the other in which case place this first:

```
If strMyString.Contains("Most Likely To Find") OrElse strMyString.Contains("Less Likely to Find") Then
    'Code
End if
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the alternative solution to check whether a particular string contains some predefined string. It uses `IndexOf` Function:

```
'this is your string
Dim strMyString As String = "aaSomethingbb"

'if your string contains these strings
Dim TargetString1 As String = "Something"
Dim TargetString2 As String = "Something2"

If strMyString.IndexOf(TargetString1) <> -1 Or strMyString.IndexOf(TargetString2) <> -1 Then

End If
```

**NOTE:** This solution has been tested with Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2):

You have `("Something2")` by itself - you need to test it so a boolean is returned:

```
If strMyString.Contains("Something") or strMyString.Contains("Something2") Then
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If strMyString.Contains("Something") or strMyString.Contains("Something2") Then

End if
```

The error indicates that the compiler thinks you want to do a bitwise `OR` on a Boolean and a string.  Which of course won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disregard whether the text is uppercase or lowercase, use this:

```
   If strMyString.ToUpper.Contains("TEXT1") OrElse strMyString.ToUpper.Contains("TEXT2") Then
        'Something
   End if
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 If strMyString.Tostring.Contains("Something") or strMyString.Tostring.Contains("Something2") Then


     End if
```

Answer (score 0):

I've approached this in a different way.  I've created a function which simply returns true or false..
Usage:

If FieldContains("A;B;C",MyFieldVariable,True|False) then

.. Do Something

End If

```
Public Function FieldContains(Searchfor As String, SearchField As String, AllowNulls As Boolean) As Boolean

       If AllowNulls And Len(SearchField) = 0 Then Return True

        For Each strSearchFor As String In Searchfor.Split(";")
            If UCase(SearchField) = UCase(strSearchFor) Then
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        Return False

    End Function
```

Comment: Rather than combining and slicing strings, which will incidentally fail if one of the string sought why not pass in the array of sought values as a `params` variable sized arg?

You'll allocate far fewer objects, not have escaping problems for your separators and it'll be faster.

Answer (score -3):

Interestingly, this solution can break, but a workaround:
Looking for my database called `KeyWorks.accdb` which must exist:

Run this:

```
Dim strDataPath As String = GetSetting("KeyWorks", "dataPath", "01", "") 'get from registry

If Not strDataPath.Contains("KeyWorks.accdb") Then....etc.
```

If my database is named `KeyWorksBB.accdb`, the `If` statement will find this acceptable and exit the `If` statement because it did indeed find `KeyWorks` and `accdb`.

If I surround the `If` statement qualifier with single quotes like `'KeyWorks.accdb'`, it now looks for all the consecutive characters in order and would enter the `If` block because it did not match.