# VB.Net string contains exact match

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I'm wondering if there is a way to search for an exact text match in a text box

for example

using "if textbox1.text.contains("Hello") then" works

however i only want it to search for text "Hello" and if i have 2 words like this

HelloFriend
Hello Friend

I only want it to find the word matching so the second statement Hello Friend and not HelloFriend as this doesn't match the keyword.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a regular expression that matches the word with word boundaries:

```
if Regex.IsMatch(textbox1.Text, "\b" + Regex.Escape("Hello") + "\b") Then
```

Comment: this works perfectly. I was using regex.ismatch but didnt know about the \b boundry tag.

Answer (score 0):

try to checkout
 [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)
or
 [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370081/vb-net-if-string-contains-value1-or-value2)

may be this one will help you :)

Comment: Please see this Meta Stackoverflow question: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really good answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)  The consensus is that links are good, but should never be the only substance in your answer.

Comment: Hi, I did see these ones but they didn't do what I was after. I was looking to just match the text i specify exactly letter for letter. Thank you for your quick reply.