# Import text from a .txt file using keywords in random positions

Tags: vb.net, import, keyword

I'm new in this great platform and I have a question in *Visual Basic.net*. 
I would like to import data from a txt file (or if you prefer a richtextbox!) using keywords that can be placed in a random position within the txt file. For example a txt like this:

`keyword       25`

or like this:

`keyword 25`

In both cases the application should be able to recognise the line because of the presence of the keyword and get the number (25) that will be saved in a variable. Of course this number can vary in different files.

I was thinking to use a code similar to this one:

```
If line.StartsWith(keyword) Then
    .....
End If
```

but the problem is that the *keyword* is not always placed as first char (there can be spaces before) and I don't know the line where this keyword is placed int the txt file.

Then I would even ask you how to get the number *25* that can be also placed in random position after the keyword (but for sure on the same line).

I hope everything is clear and thanks if you can help me.

Comment: Are you saying that every line will contain just this keyword and a number, with an arbitrary number of spaces around them?

Comment: This is very similar to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370081/vb-net-if-string-contains-value1-or-value2
please check it out

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @jmcilhinney exactly!
The txt file is like this 

'Keyword1= 25' \new line
'Keyword2=   36'  \new line
'Keyword5=      44'  \new line
'Keyword3=12'   \new line
'Keyword4 =   34'  \new line
(with random spaces around them)
I need to extract just the numbers and put them in specific variables.
What do you suggest? 

Comment: Any idea to solve this kind of problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using .TrimStart() on the lines as you read them, like so:

```
If line.TrimStart.StartsWith(keyword) Then
.......
End If
```