# How to check if a String variable contains a dot/period(.) character?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to check if a string contains a dot character, something like this

```
Dim input As String
input = "Hello."

if (input contains a dot character) then
  do something
else
  do something
End if
```

Comment: [VB.NET - If string contains "value1" or "value2"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370081/vb-net-if-string-contains-value1-or-value2)

Comment: Many .net classes have static functions and methods which are are written in plain English and are very easy to find by placing a `.` after a variable instance of that class. Check that first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The most simplest is

```
input.Contains('.')
```

Comment: Since the language tagged in the question is `vb.net`, then the answer should be `s.Contains("."c)`